# Best way to import an entire .txt. file in a single pandas row

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better way to import a txt file in a single pandas row than the solution below?

```py
import pandas as pd
with open(path_txt_file) as f:
    text = f.read().replace("\n", "")
df = pd.DataFrame([text], columns = ["text"])
```

Sample lines from the .txt file:

```
Today is a beautiful day.
I will go swimming.
```

I tried `pd.read_csv` but it is returning multiple rows due to new lines.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the csv file? For example the first rows?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` can read a txt file too if a proper delimiter is specified

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added two lines that can be used for testing purposes.

Comment: @anky_91 I am able to import it with read_csv. The issue is that multiple rows are returned instead of a single one, due to new lines in the .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the lines with [**`.str.cat()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
text = pd.read_csv(path_txt_file, sep='\n', header=None)[0].str.cat()
df = pd.DataFrame([text], columns=['text'])
```

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem. This works, but why is it better than the solution I posted?

Comment: @datapug: because Pandas usually will store and manipulate data in bulk more efficiently than when it is wrapped in Python objects.